# MySQL Query Syntax Error on escaped string

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO `5` VALUES ('photo', 'headline', 'LA Lakers', 'http://facebook.com/NUMBER', 'Here\'s video from the An...', 'NUMBER', 'http://www.facebook.com/NUMBER/posts/NUMBER', 'NUMBER'), 'https://graph.facebook.com/NUMBER/picture?access_token=AAAGGhZBZB1ZCf4BAD1fNpORWVGtWhUI5u**********************&type=normal')
```

I get this error when I try this query:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near ''https://graph.facebook.com/NUMBER/picture?access_token=AAAGGhZBZB1ZC' at line 1
```

after the individual values (NOT the whole query) have been escaped by php function mysql_real_escape_string.

I have changed all profile ids to the string NUMBER and i added the asterisks to the access token to protect my privacy. Those are not usually there.

Comment: Your last value is outside the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this; the last parameter was outside of the parenthesis.

```
INSERT INTO `5` VALUES ('photo', 'headline', 'LA Lakers', 'http://facebook.com/NUMBER', 'Here\'s video from the An...', 'NUMBER', 'http://www.facebook.com/NUMBER/posts/NUMBER', 'NUMBER', 'https://graph.facebook.com/NUMBER/picture?access_token=AAAGGhZBZB1ZCf4BAD1fNpORWVGtWhUI5u**********************&type=normal')
```

Comment: I was missing it could've sworn you were right... Nope! Thats not the problem.

Comment: Wait... oops. I've been stairing at this for hours. You are correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the round brackets in the last value of your insert query...
Further, use apostrophe in the table name...
Like this:

```
INSERT INTO '5' VALUES ('photo', 'headline', 'LA Lakers', 'http://facebook.com/NUMBER', 'Here\'s video from the An...', 'NUMBER', 'http://www.facebook.com/NUMBER/posts/NUMBER', 'NUMBER', 'https://graph.facebook.com/NUMBER/picture?access_token=AAAGGhZBZB1ZCf4BAD1fNpORWVGtWhUI5u**********************&type=normal')
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO`5`VALUES (...), 'https://graph.facebook.com/NUMBER/picture?access_token=AAAGGhZBZB1ZCf4BAD1fNpORWVGtWhUI5u**********************&type=normal'`

Take a look at your brackets, they end prematurely, which may be the error.